# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am using an `UITableView` for showing some data. Now when an user tap on a cell I appended a new cell just below the taped cell to show some more extra information. Everything is working fine. It's has two sections. Now if I tap on a cell of section 1 it's append a new cell as it should be. Then I do down scroll and the appended cell & it's parent cell is going out of the visible rect. And when I do up scroll it's shows back. No issue. But the problem is if I scroll up very fast it got crashed on the below line.

```
UITableViewCell *parentCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row]-1 inSection:[indexPath section]]];
```

In console it shows

```
***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

If I scroll slowly it's works fine only got crashed if I do it fast. And very strange is if I do the same for section 0. It's not got crashed. Guys please help me. I already spent lot of time to figure out this but fail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it not able to update the array properly before u scroll check your array count

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code if you want people to help. It looks like your row count and the number of entries in your array are out of sync

Comment: show `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` code.....

Comment: I just want to get the previous cell of the newly appended cell.

Answer (score 1):

The `-1` in `[indexPath row]-1` is almost certainly wrong; the row is zero-based and so are your data structures (well they are if you keep your data in an `NSMutableArray` or somesuch).

However this doesn't tally with the exception "5 is greater than 4", so I'm assuming you are making "+1" and "-1" adjustments here and there which is breaking your app.

I'm pretty sure you don't have to make these adjustments at all, however I cannot tell for certain without seeing more code.

Comment: This -1 is not for adjustment. when the cell is appended a button will visible on it's parent cell. I mean cell before the appended cell. And to get that cell I used the above code.